# is this the correct way to use WMI?

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

I am trying to build a tool on the server which will open the browser on the client. **note that the server and the client are in the same domain in our company**.

everything works good, but when i try this to open the browswer on the client machine

```
 string theProcessToRun = popupURL + "?CallerID=" + callerID;

                string remoteIdentifier = string.Format(@"\\{0}\root\cimv2:Win32_Process", ipAddress);
                ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass(remoteIdentifier);

                mc.InvokeMethod("Create", new[] { theProcessToRun });
```

as you see, i am using `@"\\{0}\root\cimv2:Win32_Process", ipAddress`, which ** I don't** know if it is the correct way because i am using windows client so i don't know what is this `root` has to do here

i am having this exception

```
Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
```

on this line

```
mc.InvokeMethod("Create", new[] { theProcessToRun });
```

may you help please

Comment: The documentation says: *For security reasons the Win32_Process.Create method cannot be used to start an interactive process remotely.*

Comment: @rene thanks. Then what can I use to open a browswer remotely ?

Comment: Don't do that I would say... Can't you send an email (or a task) with a link to the user? Or have a local process running in the user context that checks a db table, or a remote file or listens on a socket? Alternatively there is [this guidance on creating processes remotely](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389769(v=vs.85).aspx).